# Rally customized app - can't authenticate

Tags: rally

I'm trying to develop a rally app using the app builder. When I load App-debug.html in my browser, I am prompted to enter my user credentials in the form provided. I enter them, but the form re-appears over and over again.

I did notice that the login attempts to authenticate via https://rally1.rallydev.com:443. If I go to this in another window and enter my account details I am able to get in. However, when I do log in, there is a corporate redirect that takes place (for SSO) and I ultimately end up on us1.rallydev.com.

How would I get my app to authenticate through us1.rallydev.com. Changing urls in App.js and config.json only causes errors when trying to load javascript for APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app should always just piggyback on your existing session.  Changing the serverin config.json and re-running `rab build` should cause all traffic to go to that server- if that's not happening then that's a bug.

You won't be able to authenticate from scratch using SSO from an app, but it should have no problem re-using an existing session.

Another option is to use an API Key to develop: https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/guide/embedding_apps